# Oracle 10g and RSS feeds

Tags: oracle, rss, oracle10g

Is feeding a db in Oracle 10gR2 from an rss feed possible?  If so how do I start with this?
If not, do I have to use an intermediary (i.e. Java or something)?

The premise:

I am trying to develop an earthquake event database based on feeds from earthquakes.usgs.gov.  Using their feed I would be able to maintain a near real time db of events.  I ask about this route (RSS) because I don't want to use their software (it's limited in function) and I don't think the boys at caltech will allow me a connection to their DB to pull everything relevant.

any suggestions would be great, links to relevant information sources would be better, examples would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - and you can do it in PL/SQL.

You could use [UTL_HTTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_http.htm) to grab the raw feed and parse it yourself; or you can use dbms_xmlparser as demonstrated in this article:

http://technology.amis.nl/blog/1173/building-an-rss-feed-reader-in-plsql-using-utl_http-dbms_xmldom-and-dbms_xslprocessor-for-parsing-and-transforming

Even better - you can just take someone else's example and customise it to your requirements: http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2011/02/fun-with-rss-and-plsql-part-one.html

Comment: Thank you, this points me in the right direction (sometimes the documentation can be a bit lengthy - finding what you are looking for can be hit and miss if you don't know the right keywords).  I appreciate your help!